# Clustal Omega - convert from distance into # of substitutions

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a set of nucleotide sequences for which I have aligned using Clustal Omega. In particular, I performed a full alignment, and obtained a full distance matrix.

The distance matrix scores range between 0 and 1. I am looking to use this score to back-compute the number of different positions present in the alignment. Is this possible? If possible, I'm looking to avoid using code (my own or otherwise) to re-compute the number of positions differing between each pair of segments, and instead compute it directly from the distance score.

Here is a toy example of what I am receiving from ClustalOmega:

```
Sequence    1    2    3    4
1           0    0.1  0.06 0.1
2                0    0.4  0.23
3                     0    0.05
4                          0
```

The numbers are the "distances" as calculated by ClustalOmega. According to the README file, they are computed by the k-tuple measure. I tried parsing the original paper (published in 1983 in PNAS), but I could not figure out how k-tuple distances are computed, and I could not figure out how the distance metric (as reported like above) is computed from k-tuple distances.

I would like to convert those numbers into the `number of positions that differ between each pair of sequences when the two are aligned`. This includes substitutions, insertions, deletions. I am currently doing this for 520 sets of virus sequences. Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "positions" in your alignment? How many sequences are we talking about? Can you show an example of the matrix and your desired result?

Comment: Sure, let me update the original question.

Comment: It uses a gonet matrix to compare each of these two sequences. Since you you could have insertions and extensions as well as substitutions, it becomes a 3 parameter problem. 1*open + 6*penalty + substituion_penalty = X. X can be solved by a linear combination of subsituion_penalties, extensions, and insertions. So I think this will be really really hard.

Comment: with that being said. Clustal spits out the multiple sequence alightment. Why don't you just look at sequence 1 and sequence 2 and see what the insertions and subtitutions are!

Comment: Haha, it looks like I will have to do that in the end. I was trying to see if I could take the lazy route and not write a few lines of code. Thank you for all of your input nonetheless!

Comment: @jwillis0720 if you are still around then can you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses a gonet matrix to compare each of these two sequences. Since you you could have insertions and extensions as well as substitutions, it becomes a 3 parameter problem. 1*open + 6*penalty + substitution_penalty = X. X can be solved by a linear combination of substitution_penalties, extensions, and insertions. So I think this will be really really hard

with that being said. Clustal outputs the multiple sequence alignment. Why don't you just look at sequence 1 and sequence 2 and see what the insertions and substitutions are!